# Where to find release dates and my installation dates for kernel versions?

Tags: grub2, kernel

During boot time, I can find in grub the following menu:

[image]

I would like to know

1. when the referring patch / update version was released officially
2. when I installed it on my computer

Background: I experience(d) freezes and filesystem corruptions with one of these updates and want to track this down further.

Comment: `ls -al /boot` will show installation dates. Note: You have way too many old kernels. You assume that a kernel revision is causing your freezes and filesystem corruptions... may not be a valid assumption.

Comment: "Freezes"? "Filesystem corruption"? Sounds like overheating. However, the complete lack of details precludes more effort.